# How to display details automatically once web page is open in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a page with a list. Let the list looks something like this and we can click on the list:

## -------------

People 1

## -------------

People 2

## -------------

People 3

## -------------

What i want to do here is, if the web page is open, the system will automatically display the detail of the People 1 by default just under the list of People 1.

Then, if user click People 2, it will display People 2 details, and at the same time the details of People 1 will close up. It only show down the details for People 2 only.

Hopefully anyone can help me. Thank you.

Comment: That HTML component called ACCORDIAN. You can get example from here https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_accordion.asp . It is easy.

Comment: @Dipal — They have one already. They want to change the way the one they already have works.

Comment: @Quentin : Thanks for correction.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can achieve it via java-script function.

Give **Id** to your first person list and after page load you can trigger Click() event of that according.

```
<button class="accordion" id="section1">Section 1</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Section 2</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Section 3</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
</div>
```

following is java-script function which will be called after your page is rendered

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  $("#section1").click();
});
```